# How to stay Signed In for Gmail api without NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I want to get the messages of users by gmail api. For that google authorization is needed. I managed to authorize the user by following code -

```
      let authBtn = document.getElementById('authorize_button');

      const CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      const API_KEY = 'XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

      const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest';

      const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

      let tokenClient;
      let gapiInited = false;
      let gisInited = false;

      authBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden';

      function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', intializeGapiClient);
      }

      async function intializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES,
          callback: '',
        });

        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
          authBtn.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
          if (resp.error !== undefined) throw (resp);

          authBtn.innerText = 'Refresh';
          await getMessages();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
        }
      }
```

In above code `gapi.client.getToken() === null` is always `false`. Everytime I refresh the page I have to reauthorize user with **prompt: 'consent'**.
I also want user to stay **signed in** until user **sign out**.
How can I achieve by modifying the above code?
Can Please someone help me?

Comment: Idtoken is authentication the result of signin,   you appear to be using authencation or oauth2 no id token will be returned.  you should check this https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web

Answer (score 1):

You are using a system that requires a server-side authentication flow, read about properly handling that here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token

The `gapi` JavaScript is browser code (you obviously know this because the question specifies all sorts of DOM related code), and therefore Authentication is fundamentally not going to be possible entirely in the browser without a server-side flow to handle the callbacks from Google that occur out-of-band from the browser.

The only exception I can find to the rule of having a server-side component is to credential manager API:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-browsers-native-credential-manager

It seems to significantly simplify things, but from what I can tell supports Chrome only (maybe including chrome-based browsers Edge, Brave, etc. but maybe not Chromium as it seems to be needing Google accounts in the browser itself, e.g. login is not managed by your code for your website but the user using the browser directly before they visit your site)

Comment: I used **browsers native credential maganer** but every time it prompts _signing you in_ , page gets refreshed and process continues

Comment: @Shrey Read the first line again, around ‘server side’

Comment: @Shrey in less words, you can't do this without node.js as you requested.

Comment: Can I do that with **Cookies**? Or Out Of Options

Comment: "I used browsers native credential manager" and if your browser (not your site code) is signed in to Google it'll stay signed in after browser restarts, thats the Chrome function and nothing to do with your site, all your site then does is request access to the google account. But of course if they are not signed into the browser when your site requested access, it'll prompt them everytime until they choose to do it in the browser themselves directly, nothing your site code can do